# Incrementing counter in Stream foreach Java 8

Tags: java

I'd like to increment a `counter` which is an `AtomicInteger` as I loop through using `foreach`

```
public class ConstructorTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    List<Foo> fooList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Foo>());
    List<String> userList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
    userList.add("username1_id1");
    userList.add("username2_id2");

    userList.stream().map(user -> new Foo(getName(user), getId(user))).forEach(fooList::add);
    //how do I increment the counter in the above loop

    fooList.forEach(user -> System.out.println(user.getName() + "   " + user.getId()));
}

private static String getName(String user) {
    return user.split("_")[0];
}

private static String getId(String user) {
    return user.split("_")[1];
}
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Depends on where you want to increment.

Either

```
userList.stream()
        .map(user -> {
               counter.getAndIncrement();
               return new Foo(getName(user), getId(user));
            })
        .forEach(fooList::add);
```

or

```
userList.stream()
        .map(user -> new Foo(getName(user), getId(user)))
        .forEach(foo -> {
            fooList.add(foo);
            counter.getAndIncrement();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @bradimus. I did the second one and it worked. The purpose of my question was to see if I could combine `Method Reference` with another method call. Guess it's not possible. I will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 33):

We can use incrementAndGet method of Atomic Integer.

```
  AtomicInteger count=new AtomicInteger(0);

  list.forEach(System.out.println(count.incrementAndGet());
```

Comment: https://codippa.com/increment-variable-foreach-lambda-expression-java/

Answer (score 4):

can also be done using Stream.peek()

```
userList.stream()
    .map(user -> new Foo(getName(user), getId(user)))
    .peek(u -> counter.getAndIncrement())
    .forEach(fooList::add);
```

Comment: what's the difference b/w peek() & forEach()?

Comment: It is not advisable to use `stream.peek` for the above scenario. As oracle document says, `This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline` [JavaDoc#Peek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-). It's better to use `getAndIncrement()` inside `forEach` as @bradimus mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

how about using

```
java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
```

example:

```
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();

            actionList.forEach(action -> {
                   index.getAndIncrement();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can increment by chunk.

```
private Integer chunkSize = 500;
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
                utils.partitionBySize(yourList, chunkSize).forEach(x ->
                        {
                            --do something
                            count.addAndGet((int) x.stream().count());
                            LOGGER.info("count : " + count);
                        }

                );
```

Answer (score -3):

You can change it to an anonymous class:

```
        userList.stream().map(new Function<String, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object apply(String user) {
                counter.addAndGet(1);
                return new Foo(getName(user), getId(user));
            }
        }).forEach(fooList::add);
```

Remember to make `counter` `final`.

Comment: Why create an anonymous class when a simple lambda will suffice?

Comment: @bradimus - No real reason - when you posted your answer it was better than mine but mine suggests another alternative so I left it here. BTW - you should probably add the note about making the counter final.