# How to count the iteration of lambda in Java streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream

### I have below solution with counter variable, is there any preferred way to get the counter of lambda iteration ?

```
class Employee {
    String name;
    int salary;
}

public class Calculator {
    private static Integer counter;
    public void method1() {
        counter = 0; // Instead of this, is there any default counter ?
        List<Employee> emp = getData()
        List<Employee> updated = emp.stream().map(Calculator::increaseSalary).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("counter = " + counter);
    }
    
    private Employee increaseSalary(Employee emp) {
        counter++;
        emp.setSalary(50000);
        return emp;
    }   
}
```

---

Comment: What about `updated.size()`? Also `increaseSalary()` will not compile due to the missing return statement. Finally `map()` functions should be pure, and thus not alter the data: it makes things confusing and can potentially break.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, size() is bit costly operation. "increaseSalary()" its just an illustration. Apologies for the typo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incrementing counter in Stream foreach Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38568129/incrementing-counter-in-stream-foreach-java-8)

Comment: @karthick, which implementation of `List` are you using?

Comment: How is `size()` costly? If anything, building the list could be costly. If you don’t need the list, just use `Stream.count()`… but then I wouldn’t rely on the assumption that the `map()` operation will be executed.

Comment: @GauthamM Thanks for the reply, but they are using a counter and incrementing. My question is without an extra counter variable, how do we get the number of iterations in the lambda.

Comment: @DidierL its a huge collection, i was thinking anyways we are iterating through the list, when converting into a map, wanted to find how many times it got iterated.

Comment: @karthick If you are not using any `filter` on the stream, then it would be same as the size of the list. `size()` is not a costly operation as it is stored as a property in the list implementation. And it is just a `return size;` in the source code (for most implementations)

Comment: Thanks folks, I guess let me use size()